# SVG file not saving as drawn in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export

Below is an image of the logo I have created in illustrator CS6:

[image]

However, when I save the file as an SVG and then view it, it has been saved looking like so:

[image]

Notice how the text is changed to lower case and appears narrower when it's saved as an SVG. I'm using the Playfair Display font from Google Fonts.

Any thoughts on what I might do to fix this issue or why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: I think the problem is not the line but the text, in the original example it's uppercase and in the example SVG it's lowercase,  this makes the text narrower, therefore the line looks longer being the same in both examples.

Comment: Ah great point @Danielillo. I think you are correct. I'll edit the question accordingly. Any idea on what might be causing the text issue? The font I'm using is downloaded from google fonts (Playfair Display)

Comment: @Danielillo, thanks to your prompt I was able to solve the problem. The problem was that I hadn't used `create outline` on the text prior to trying to save it as an SVG. Works perfectly now. Thank you for chiming in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to `create outline` on the text before saving as SVG

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/84669)

Comment: @Ovaryraptor: This looks like a valid [self-answer](/help/self-answer) to me. It could be improved with some more information though.